# Error while compiling node.js addon on Zynq board (arm)

Tags: node.js, arm, add-on, zynq

I want to use C++ addon for node.js on Zynq board (armv7).

I am able to use the addon and run successfully on the host machine(Linux).

When I try to cross compile the addon and tried to run the addon on Zynq board I am getting the error below:

```
module.js:355
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^

Error: /sd/addon.node: undefined symbol: node_module_register
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/sd/hello.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I am using node-gyp to cross compile the addon to arm.

```
AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ LINK=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ node-gyp clean configure --arch=arm rebuild
```

What might be the issue?